# What allows a function to store a reference to the lexical environment of other function?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I generally understand how closures work. For instance, in this example, the lexical environment of `outerFunc` is not removed because it is referenced by its inner function `innerFunc`.

```
function outerFunc() {
  let value = 'JavaScript';
  function innerFunc() {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
let result = outerFunc();
```

If we go deeper, we can say that `Reference` keep this link to the outer lexical environment. The `Reference` is the component of lexical environment:

> A lexical environment consists of two main components: the environment
> record and a reference to the outer (parent) lexical environment ([the source](https://medium.com/@5066aman/lexical-environment-the-hidden-part-to-understand-closures-71d60efac0e0)).

The lexical environment, in turn, is created every time when function is called:

> Every time the JavaScript engine creates an execution context to execute the function or global code, it also creates a new lexical environment to store the variable defined in that function during the execution of that function ([the source](https://blog.bitsrc.io/a-beginners-guide-to-closures-in-javascript-97d372284dda#:%7E:text=Every%20time%20the%20JavaScript%20engine,that%20holds%20identifier%2Dvariable%20mapping)).

All this information makes me question: "How can `innerFunc` function hold a link to the lexical environment of `outerFunc` function, if **this link can be stored only in the Reference, which is contained in the lexical environment, which, in turn, is created only when this function is called?"**

So I think this is not logical: the function hasn't been called yet, but it already has a lexical environment, which stores a link to the external lexical environment in relation to it.

Comment: "*if this link can be stored only in the Reference*" - that's where you got wrong. A function object is not a lexical environment. It simply directly contains the link to the outer environment in which it has been defined. The lexical environments that will get created when the function is called will *also* store this link, and their reference is in fact initialised with the value stored in the function object itself.

Comment: @Bergi I see, when function is created it has this link to the outer lexical environment. And when function is called, the Reference is created (but it's empty for now). And then the Reference takes this link from function object. Am I right?